# Progress of Activity sets not visible in HR lifecycle events case in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

Hi currently I am working on New Hire Onboarding in using ServiceNow.
After HR case got created in  HR lifecycle events case the progress of Activity sets is not visible and Activity set Execution UI link is not present in Related links of same HR case, but UI action for it got created and Form link is marked as Active still it is not visible.

[HR case got created for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAFSF.png)

Above image is the HR case got created for me and it is not proper.

[HR case that should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2o2v.png)

Above image shows the proper HR lifecycle events case that should be.